# Is there a way to mock a filesystem for unit testing in Scala

Tags: scala, filesystems, mocking

I'm looking for a way to mock a filesystem in Scala.  I'd like to do something like this:

```
class MyMainClass(fs: FileSystem) {
   ...
}
```

normal runtime:

```
val fs = FileSystem.default
main = new MyMainClass(fs)
```

test time:

```
val fs = new RamFileSystem
main = new MyMainClass(fs)
```

My examples look a lot like Scala-IO and I thought it might be my answer.  However, it doesn't look like all the core functionality in Scala-IO works with the `FileSystem` abstraction.  In particular, I can't read from a `Path` or apply `Path.asInput`.  Further, several of the abstractions like `Path` and `Resource` seem tightly bound to `FileSystem.default`.

I also googled some interesting stuff in Scala-Tools, but that project seems to be defunct.

Rob

Comment: Scala-Tools per se is no more, but the projects whose artifacts were hosted there have just moved elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to create your own abstraction. Something like this:

```
trait MyFileSystem { def getPath() }
```

Then you can implement it with both a real FileSystem and a mocked version.

```
class RealFileSystem(fs: FileSystem) extends MyFileSystem {
  def getPath() = fs.getPath()
}

class FakeFileSystem extends MyFileSystem {
  def getPath() = "/"
}
```

And then MyMainClass can require a MyFileSystem instead of a FileSystem

```
class MyMainClass(fs: MyFileSystem)
main = new MyMainClass(new RealFileSystem(FileSystem.default))
test = new MyMainClass(new FakeFileSystem)
```

Comment: A good compromise if I can't find what I want.  Maybe I can wrap Scala IO to get exactly what I want for mocking but still take advantage of the Scala idioms in Scala IO.

Comment: I've also been told Java 7 or 8 may have what I'm looking for.  I'll probably look into that even though I'd prefer idiomatic Scala.